How to deploy an application using IAM Identity to access AWS SDK when session expires every X hours
I am new to AWS and I finally figured out how to setup IAM Identity to use the SDK. However, to use it I need to use my CLI to login to initiate a new session which requires a browser to open and some fancy 2-factor method using my phone.
Something does not seem right because once my application gets bundled up into a container, how am I expected to refresh the session every 12 hours, for each container I run?
I have considered the long-term auth method but AWS strongly recommends against that.

AWS provides a machine role, which is an IAM role that generates temporary credentials and is associated with the container or the virtual machines on which the application runs. Utilizing such roles, you don't need to specify/configure access credentials when using SDK. Details are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html.
This method is the appropriate way to give programmatic access to AWS services from applications that run on AWS infrastructure.

This is exactly what I have except I have the preferred method by using IAM Identity Temporary Access.

If you look at the following link they recommend IAM Identity Center, the above is using IAM: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/sdk-programmatic-access.html

I also noticed this; "If you are developing on an AWS resource, such as Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) or AWS Cloud9, we recommend getting credentials from that service instead." This just sounds like a mess: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/access-sso.html
